# ALT text required each time an image is used

Tags: alt, sitecore8.2

Even if the ALT text field is completed when the image is uploaded, each time I'm trying to use that image I get a message that the ALT text is required to be completed. I'm using Sitecore 8.2. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add some information about your problem and one can reproduce it.

Comment: These are the steps to repoduce it:
1.Add an image in Sitecore Media Library( the ALT text field is completed during this step)
2.Use the image in a component (here the ALT text field is required again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but with a fresh installation of 8.2 I am reproducing your steps, and there is no issue. Two things you may want to consider:

1) Since the Alt field is not shared, are you looking at a different language version?

2) When looking at the properties of an image the alternate text field will be empty, but under that it will state default alternate text with what you entered.

Comment: Thanks JasonM!
The problem was the one you mentioned at 1), more exactly, the alt text is set only for the default language version of the image.